# Битовые поля

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, у меня 3 вопроса, по поводу битовых полей, именно:

1. Когда длинна битового поля более 8 бит (размера ячейки RAM) ячейки, выделенные под это битовое поле объединяются?
2. Когда я создаю переменную, тип данных, которой менее 8 бит (размера ячейки RAM), например, переменная в 7 бит, остается 1 свободный бит, может ли он быть задействован (включен) в другое битовое поле или он будет считаться занятым?
3. Могу ли по средствам языка C++, создавать переменные более 64 бит, если нет, то возможно это реализуется на ассемблере? Напишите, пожалуйста, подробно. Спасибо.

Comment: Мне кажется, сперва стоит определиться в терминологии и контексте того, отчего у вас возникли такие вопросы. Какую задачу вы хотите решить, узнав ответы на эти вопросы?

Comment: Задачи пока нет, чисто теория.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Объединяются
2. Зависит от компилятора.
3. Можно и на С++. Можно сделать любые типы данных, но операции с ними придется реализовывать очень хитро. Можно для них сделать объектные обертки, реализовать в виде массивов, перегрузить операторы, а внутри проводить с ними всякие хитрые операции.

Comment: 2.компилятор MinGw(g++), стоит ли мучатся с переменными до 8бит или нет?

Comment: Никогда не работал с битовыми полями. Поэкспериментируйте.

Comment: Я слабо представляю как поставить такой эксперимент.

Comment: >стоит ли мучатся с переменными до 8бит ?

Смотря зачем. Выигрыш в памяти будет минимальный, скорость доступа скорее всего ниже. В повседневных задачах (если вы конечно не пишете архиватор или не работаете с железом) битовые поля используются редко.

Comment: То есть битовые операции замедляют работы программы?

Comment: Эксперимент очень простой: определяем структуру с битовыми полями, далее смотрим размер этой структуры с помощью sizeof.

Comment: Спасибо, 2 пункт исчерпан.Можете дать окончательный вердикт замедляют ли битовые операции работу программы, именно: умножение деление на степень двойки, возведение двойки в степень, и оправдана ли замена булевого массива на цепочку битов?

Comment: >То есть битовые операции замедляют работы программы?

Ну не совсем так, просто чтобы например вытащить 2 бита из середины байта, фактически применяются операции сдвига и битовые логические операции.

Comment: Везде пишут, что замедляется. 

Относительно использования набора битов, то это имеет смысл только для экономии памяти. Многие операции с ним будут замедлены или затруднены. 

Кстати, так реализован в STL контейнер vector<bool>. Как правило, его не рекомендуют для регулярного использования.

Comment: @mikillskegg, размер структуры будет целое число в байтах)

Comment: Ну так это и надо определить - )))

Comment: С размерами вообще интересно (надо играться, изучать). Собственно поигрался с разными типами (signed, unsigned, signed long, signed long long) и размерами полей (от 2 до 62 бит) на 32-bit (MinGW Windows 7) и 64-bit gcc.

32-bit gcc от полей длинее 32 сходит с ума. Т.е. компилирует (в пределах разумного, следит за соответствием длины поля и максимального размера типа), но с sizeof структуры при длинных полях явно врет (иногда выдает 0 !!!). Вообще пытатется упаковать в массив int. Поле через границу ячейки (вроде бы) не переходит.

64-бит значительно лучше. За основу берет (сейчас продолжу)

Comment: (продолжение)

размер типа максимально длинного поля (например long (8 байт)) и пытается что можно туда паковать. Если что-то не влезает, то может упаковть его в int (4 байта). Т.е. из печати sizeof всей структуры видно, что смешивает long и int. Ошибок у 64-bit gcc не заметил (вообще у них и версии разные).

---

По поводу битовых строк и bool. для экономии памяти bool не годятся. IMHO поля тоже (м.б. просто не умею с ними работать). Надо самому делать из массива char.

---

Арифметика с полями. Если нужны вычисления со знаком (скажем для 12 (или 48) разрядных чисел) - то поля это OK++.

Answer (score 1):

2.Пример из википедии:

```
struct rgb
{
    unsigned char r:2;
    unsigned char g:3;
    unsigned char b:3;
};
```

Все 3 битовых поля будут находиться в одной и той же ячейке памяти.

3.Есть такое понятие как [длинная арифметика](ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Длинная_арифметика). Числа фактически хранятся как массивы, для арифметических операций пишутся соответствующие функции. Для большинства языков программирования есть готовые библиотеки для работы с "длинными" числами.

Comment: "Все 3 битовых поля будут находиться в одной и той же ячейке памяти." длиной 4 (!) байта. Хотя это для gcc. Возможно другой компилятор положит их в 1 байт.

Comment: Вон оно как... Исправил, теперь всё в одном байте)

Comment: Помоему лучше делать не структуру а union, у меня компилятор даже на пустую структуру выделяет 1 байт.

Comment: А Вы сколько байт под свои поля хотите ? Меньше одного никак.